# How to prevent Python Bottle from reporting every request to the console?

Tags: python, bottle

I am running a server using Python Bottle. It works perfectly fine, but it logs every single request it handles to the console, which slows it down. Is there a way to instruct it **not** to make those logs to the console?

Example code:

```
from bottle import route, run
@route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello, world!'
run(host = 'localhost', port = 8080)
```

Example output (which I get every time a request to `localhost:8080/` is made):

```
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Jun/2015 11:23:24] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 244
```

Comment: @Paul: I added example code and output. I have no idea what werkzeug is, what components bottle is made of, and which component of bottle it is that originates these log message. It does seem similar to the question you linked to, but, indeed, my question is about bottle, not about flask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the `quiet` argument to the `run` call:

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello, world!'

run(host = 'localhost', port = 8080, quiet=True)
```

See the [API reference](http://bottlepy.org/docs/stable/api.html).